# How can I use vue-i18n in Vite to translate html?

Tags: vue.js, vite, vue-i18n

I am using Vite with Vue 3 and vue-i18n. The site has html formatted pages which need to be displayed in the appropriate locale.
When loading the locale files I get `[plugin:unplugin-vue-i18n] Detected HTML in '...' message.` where ... is a message containing html markup - even though I set `sanitizeHtml: false`.

My vite.config.js is

```
// Plugins
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

// Utilities
import { resolve, dirname } from 'node:path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n']
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        sanitizeHtml: false,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls }
    }),
    // https://lokalise.com/blog/vue-i18n/#Installing_and_configuring_the_Vue_I18n_plugin
    VueI18nPlugin({
      include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './src/i18n/locales/**'), // provide a path to the folder where you'll store translation data (see below)
    }),
    // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
      styles: {
        configFile: 'src/styles/settings.scss',
      },
    }),
  ],
  define: { 'process.env': {} },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.jsx',
      '.mjs',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx',
      '.vue',
    ],
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved adding in `vite.config.js`

```
plugins: [
  VueI18nPlugin({
    ...
    strictMessage: false
  }),
...
]
```

The "strictMessage" option was added in version 0.10.0 (March 22, 2023) of the unplugin-vue-i18n plugin ([unplugin-vue-i18n changelog](https://github.com/intlify/bundle-tools/blob/main/packages/unplugin-vue-i18n/CHANGELOG.md#intlifyunplugin-vue-i18n0100-2023-03-22))